# Can only perform GET requests in Tornado test

Tags: tornado, python-unittest, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm trying to test a Tornado request handler that uses asyncio and the new `async def` syntax. GET requests seem to work, but other requests fail.

```
import asyncio

import tornado.platform.asyncio as tasyncio
from tornado import testing
from tornado import web


class Handler(web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.write('spam')

    get = put = post


class HandlerTest(testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return web.Application([('/', Handler)])

    def get_new_ioloop(self):
        return tasyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop()

    def test_get(self):
        response = self.fetch('/', method='GET')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)

    def test_put(self):
        response = self.fetch('/', method='PUT')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)

    def test_post(self):
        response = self.fetch('/', method='POST')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)
```

When running the handler in an interactive interpreter, it works fine:

```
>>> app = web.Application([('/', Handler)])
>>> tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
>>> app.listen(8080)
<tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer object at 0x7fbf290f3fd0>
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

So my question is; how can I test POST methods of a Tornado/asyncio request handler with unittest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing `body` in `fetch`, even empty. It is required for post/put requests - I've enclosed the working code at the bottom.

It seems that `fetch`'s (stop/wait) hide the meaningful error. For test I've changed it to general async test:

```
from tornado.testing import gen_test

class HandlerTest(testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return web.Application([('/', Handler)])

    def get_new_ioloop(self):
        return tasyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop()

    @gen_test
    def test_put(self):
        response = yield self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url('/'), method='PUT')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)
```

Produces proper error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_put (__main__.HandlerTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 132, in __call__
    result = self.orig_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 525, in post_coroutine
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 453, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 179, in throw
    return self.__wrapped.throw(tp, *rest)
  File "test.py", line 35, in test_put
    response = yield self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url('/'), method='PUT')
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 264, in <lambda>
    future, lambda future: callback(future.result()))
  File "/tmp/t35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 353, in _on_connect
    ('not ' if body_expected else '', self.request.method))
ValueError: Body must not be None for method PUT (unless allow_nonstandard_methods is true)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s
```

Working code:

```
import tornado.platform.asyncio as tasyncio
from tornado import testing
from tornado import web

class Handler(web.RequestHandler):
    async def post(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        self.write('spam')

    get = put = post


class HandlerTest(testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return web.Application([('/', Handler)])

    def get_new_ioloop(self):
        return tasyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop()

    def test_get(self):
        response = self.fetch('/', method='GET')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)

    def test_put(self):
        response = self.fetch('/', method='PUT', body=b'')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)

    def test_post(self):
        response = self.fetch('/', method='POST', body=b'')
        self.assertEqual(b'spam', response.body)

import unittest    
unittest.main()
```